# Preimage of a prime ideal in a ring homeomorphism exercise.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was looking for an alternative answer to prove that given $A$ and $B$ commutative rings with unity and $\phi :A \rightarrow B$ homeomorphism, then if $J \subset B $ is a prime ideal $\Rightarrow$ $\phi^{-1}(J)$ is a prime ideal in A.
My idea was to use the fact that $J$ is prime $\Leftrightarrow$ $B/J$ is an integral domain and $\alpha :A/\phi^{-1}(J) \rightarrow B/J$ is homeomorphism + injective, then i just have to prove that $\alpha$ is surjective to have that $\alpha$ is a isomorphism, which will show us that $A/\phi^{-1}(J)$
is an integral domai and implies that $\phi^{-1}(J)$ is prime.
Is this process righ? Because I don't think that i can show that $\alpha$ is surjective, so do I really have to show the that, isn't injective enought for our problem? 
Thank you for your time, have a nice day.

Comment: Injective is enough because a subring of an integral domain is an integral domain.

Comment: If $\phi$ itself isn't surjective then there's no reason to expect $\alpha$ to be surjective. Consider $J=(0)\subset\mathbb Q$ with $\phi:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$ the natural embedding.

Comment: I got it now, thank you!